# Synology DS410 - migrating from RAID-10 to RAID-5

Tags: raid, nas, synology

I have a Synology DS410 NAS. It has 4 HDDs in RAID-10. I need to switch to RAID-5, for better usage of available disk space. This is not an uptime-critical system, it can be unavailable for the users during the whole process.

Is it possible to achieve this goal without wiping the NAS clean and starting anew (doing all the configs, re-installings and re-configuring apps etc.)?

Answer (score -1):

I had to do this and you can change RAID types depending on your RAID starting type. I think this can be even done online and no data loss.

> Volumes and disk groups can be changed from one RAID type to another
>   without losing existing data. For example, you can create a RAID 1
>   volume on your Synology NAS, and later change to RAID 5 if you install
>   more hard drives

**GUIDE**
https://www.synology.com/en-uk/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/StorageManager/volume_diskgroup_change_raid_type

My recommendation however would be to use SHR/SHR-2 to better use the space and expand the drives, at a later stage. This uses the space much more efficiently.

Look at synology's RAID calculator:
https://www.synology.com/en-us/support/RAID_calculator

Any other help needed let me know

Comment: Cite and quote the relevant part of the guide that answers the question

Comment: Not too sure what you mean here but will try my best... Looks interesting... You need to be clear.

Comment: What do I mean:  You mention a guide, but when I made the comment, you didn't quote anything from the guide.  I believe saying you need to cite and quote all relevant information from your link is clear.

Comment: Is this a requirement? I thought just by reading they could see the solution?

Comment: - Your answer should provide all the information to answer the question that was asked, I as the reader, shouldn't have to go to the another website.  There are numerous websites where an answer like that is alright, Superuser, isn't one of those.

Comment: I have already switched to RAID-5, though unfortunately that needed some downtime. 

About SHR - I'm not overly confident about using it, Is it possible to recover data from the hard disks in case of a motherboard failure? I know it's possible (though difficult) with RAIDs.

Comment: From my understanding about RAID 5 if the RAID controller goes down, you would need an exact copy of the controller and then it should be rebuild able. I don't have access to another controller to test this out. So essentially if you buy the same model of your current NAS you should be able to swap the disks to there and recover.

Comment: Also you can recover using diskinternals software: http://www.diskinternals.com/raid-recovery/how_to.shtml Seems to be good. I am using SHR and it is good especially if you don't want to set up RAID yourself. It's an automatic style of RAID and expanding into another RAID type.

Comment: Sorry one more comment as it doesn't let me update the previous ones, make sure you have working backups either to cloud or to USB to protect your data against any other hardware failure that way you're sure you have all your data. Synology provides all the software to do this. I would suggest also test recovery to make sure all intact and working as expected. Try googling bullet proof backup strategy.